# Error in displaying and reading image in opencv

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, opencv3.0

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('/home/pi/Downloads/download.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow(img)

cv2.waitkey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Its throwing an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Exp/opcv.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.imshow(img)
TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found
```

Just trying to open a image using opencv and python. But it shows that funky error. Also i'm very new to both programming and opencv.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCV's `cv2.imshow()` expects two parameters:

1. The name of the window to show;
2. The image itself.

So, what your error `TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found`  is saying, is that the second parameter is missing, since the function is interpreting your `img` variable as the window name.

Besides that, `cv2.waitkey(0)` will also generate an error, the right function name is `cv2.waitKey(0)` (With capital K).

So the right code will be:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('/home/pi/Downloads/download.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('My window',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you, it cleared my doubts. Also how do i close this question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a window name in the first parameter of `cv2.imshow()` like `cv2.imshow('image',img)`